# cannot access the array from class array

Tags: c++

I found that my program are some bug, the reason is because I can access the data from the class array

HERE IS the class code

```
void Date::initialize(){
string monthNames[] = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
int monthDays[] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
};
```

Here is the header file Date.h, the above code is store in Date.cpp and use main.cpp to load it

```
class Date{
private:
int day;
int month;
int year;
string monthNames[12];
int monthDays[12];
```

Comment: You initialized two local arrays and throwed them away.

Comment: how to solve it? The requirement of the program is must use initialize() to initialize the arrays – monthNames and monthDays

Answer (score 2):

```
void Date::initialize()
{
     string monthNames[] = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
     copy(monthNames, monthNames + 12, this->monthNames);
}
```

You create a local array, which is logical because you can only initialize an array with braces, not assign to it. So you create a local array. Now you need to copy it to your actual member, which is `this->monthNames`. Same for the other array. Take a look at the [`copy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/) function. If you are not allowed to use stl algorithms, you can copy using a good old for loop.

Answer (score 2):

You just defined local variables, so you have to copy their data to intialize class properties.

```
void Date::initialize(){
    // make the data static not to initialize them every time this function is called
    static string monthNamesData[] = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
    static int monthDaysData[] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(monthNames) / sizeof(*monthNames); i++){
        monthNames[i] = monthNamesData[i];
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(monthDays) / sizeof(*monthDays); i++){
        monthDays[i] = monthDaysData[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays `monthNames` and `monthDays` are declared as local variables of the member function `initialize`

```
void Date::initialize(){
string monthNames[] = 
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
int monthDays[] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
};
```

They are destroyed after exiting the function.

Try instead

```
#include <array>

//...

class Date{
private:
int day;
int month;
int year;
std::array<string, 12> monthNames;
std::array<int, 12> monthDays;

//...

void Date::initialize(){
monthNames = { {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"} };
monthDays = { {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31} };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Private member variables can only be accessed outside their class  by a PUBLIC member function (but the declaration of this function must be inside class which I think you have done). Is your initialize() function public? because I don't think so. In case of Classes, everything is PRIVATE BY DEFAULT so make sure that your initialize() is declared inside class but under PUBLIC heading.